# Question about polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

What can be said about pairs of polynomials $P, Q\in\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$, such that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial z}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}\in\mathbb{C}[x]$?

I am interested in examples of such $P, Q$.

The similar question can be asked if we replace $\mathbb{C}[x]$ with any field $F$ of characteristic zero and $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$ with $F[y, z]$.

Comment: The pair of such polynomials forms a set? I don't know what this question aims at.

Comment: These pairs form a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-submodule in $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]^2$. For example, it obviously holds if $P$ or $Q$ in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: Is that set of pairs closed under addition? That’s a nonlinear differential operator...

Comment: To start with you could ask the question in $L[y,z]$ for $L$ a field of characteristic zero, then specify to $L=\mathbf{C}(x)$, and then intersect with $A[y,z]$ with $A=\mathbf{C}[x]$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler is right. Actually, for every $(P,Q)$ we can write $(P,Q)=(P,P)+(0,Q-P)$, and both pairs $(P,P)$ and $(0,Q-P)$ satisfy the equation, but not $(P,Q)$ in general.

Comment: It is not additive. Right now I am also interested in any not trivial examples. By trivial I mean $P, Q\in\mathbb{C}[x, y]$, or $P, Q\in\mathbb{C}[x, z]$, also $(P, Q) = (f(x)\cdot y, g(x)\cdot z)$.

Comment: For any scalar ring, on the $L$-algebra $L[y,z]$, the usual product along with $\{P,Q\}=\partial_yP\partial_zQ-\partial_zP\partial_yQ$ form a commutative Poisson algebra. That is, $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is a Lie bracket, and is a derivation (for the multiplication) with respect to each variable. I don't know to which extent this can answer the question, but at least it's a very well-studied kind of structure. See Wikipedia: [Poisson algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_algebra).

Comment: For the last question (for simplicity, take $F=\mathbb{C}$), I suppose you know that the these can be split into two cases, one in which you get that Jacobian to be zero and the other non-zero. The latter leads you to the notorious Jacobian conjecture and the former can be completely characterized.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, from Jacobian conjecture for $F = \mathbb{C}(x)$ there exist polynomials $R, T\in\mathbb{C}^{[2]}$ with $0\not= R(P, Q) = T(P, Q)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$.